# document.elementFromPoint in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery method which returns an element which lies closest to a specified point in the window like document.elementFromPoint Javascript method?

Comment: Why not just use the vanilla JS function?  If you store the return value in a variable you can wrap it in the jQuery object and do whatever you need to it.

Comment: No particular reason actually, just curiosity whether it can be done with writing less code or not

Comment: jQuery has made folks lazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no such method provided by jQuery itself. You may try a plugin like this instead: http://gilmoreorless.github.io/jquery-nearest/

Answer (score 3):

I would advise, if you plan to use the vanilla JS function, to be mindful of cross-browser compatability. Quirks Mode tests [1] reveal differences in the way Opera and Safari interpret coordinates when the document has been scrolled away from it's  initial position. It is possible to use feature detection [2], rather than browser detection, to handle the different coordinate spaces robustly.

> [1] http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/elementfrompoint.html
>
> [2] http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/